# Pentaho marketplace not appearing in Pentaho CE 8.0 for Mac OS

Tags: python, plugins, pentaho

On Mac OS Sierra `10.12.6`, I've recently installed Pentaho Community Edition (CE) `8.0` after my Enterprise Edition (EE) trial ended. EE had marketplace built in as a menu option but that's been removed from CE. Moreover, all my plugins have been removed (I was using the [CPython Script Executor](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/CPython+Script+Executor) plugin).

**Problem**: I cannot get Pentaho Marketplace / plugins to work. The thing is, [Pentaho docs](https://community.hds.com/docs/DOC-1009874) claim Pentaho CE 6.0+ already comes with marketplace:

> If you're using the Community Edition of Pentaho 6.0+ you don't have to worry about this - Marketplace comes with it and it's ready to be used.

This is clearly wrong, and [I'm not the only one experiencing this.](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/206210-Pentaho-6-1-CE-where-is-Marketplace/)

I tried to install Marketplace `6.0` from [Pentaho Marketplace](http://www.pentaho.com/marketplace/), the latest version, but the download link brings you to a `404` page.

This [Pentaho forums](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/196100-where-is-marketplace-in-6-0-CE/) suggested marketplace `5.4`. So I downloaded that, unzipped `marketplace/` folder into `data-integration/system` (path suggested [here in Pentaho Forums](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/196100-where-is-marketplace-in-6-0-CE/page2/)) and restarted Pentaho Data Integration App. Marketplace did not appear.

Likewise, [Pentaho Forums](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/196100-where-is-marketplace-in-6-0-CE/) suggested adding `pentaho-marketplace` to `/Applications/data-integration/system/karaf/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`:

```
#
# Comma separated list of features to install at startup
#
featuresBoot=config,pentaho-client-minimal,pentaho-marketplace
```

Again, I've restarted Pentaho App and Marketplace still does not appear.

Then I found I needed to restart the Pentaho BI server ([info here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0H0/Start_and_Stop_the_Pentaho_Server_for_Configuration)):

```
./ctlscript.sh stop pentahoserver
```

Trying to do this I get

> $ ./ctlscript.sh stop pentahoserver
>
> /Applications/Pentaho/server/pentaho-server/tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : Pentaho Server could not be stopped

Via `sudo`:

> $ sudo ./ctlscript.sh stop pentahoserver
>
> Execution by root not allowed

**Question**: How can I get Marketplace to appear, or if it's too much trouble, how can I simply just install the Python plugin I need? The problem is, [the only available blog on it](http://markahall.blogspot.de/2016/01/cpython-scripting-in-pentaho-data.html) shows that I need to get the plugin from marketplace.

---

**EDIT**: for `.sh` script to run, you need to close down postgresql connection.

---

**EDIT 2**: I gave up on getting Marketplace to work and found CPython plugin here: http://www.pentaho.com/marketplace/. I unzipped into plugins and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the CPython Script Executor plugin in the (CE) edition by accessing the Marketplace from within the Spoon client menu.  The Marketplace was located under the Tools menu.